# Could a question regarding species restoration be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If a user would be working on a non-artistic restoration of an extinct species, and at the end (or even in the process) of the work would like to get sure, whether he did everything scientifically correctly, could he post a question asking such, without being off-topic?

Comment: why would it be off-topic?

Comment: @AliceD Just haven't seen any, that's why I have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may still be misunderstanding your question - but -

Depending on whether such a question meets the regular question standards, I do not see any reason why it should be off topic here. Whether one would ethically agree with such practices is not of relevance for whether it is on- or off-topic.

Comment: Asking whether every part of the restoration is scientifically correct, would not be too broad?

Comment: @FloriOn - as per answer above, that is what I mean with *"...[if the] question meets the regular question standards"*